# Best Method for Connecting to Oracle Databases

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, database-connection

There are a number of ways to connect to an Oracle database in R. Some popular packages include ROracle, RODBC, ODBC, DBI, and many others.  For connecting to an Oracle database, which package/approach is best?  I recognize that "best" is subjective, so comparisons across metrics and discussions of limitations/benefits for each approach would be very helpful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This will be soon closed as *off topic*, but important thing is to decide, if you want to perform your R calculation *in the database* (and pay additional licence) then use `ORE`. Otherwise plays your prefecences to *JDBC* or *ODBC* a role which determines the package (add prefix `R`).

Answer (score 1):

In any case, I would probably recommend to use the driver built by the vendor that is builds the database. In this case, [ROracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/roracle.html) because if there was a bug you encountered, you could log a support ticket with Oracle to have it fixed. If the driver was built by someone else Oracle could blame the other vendor's driver, and the vendor could blame Oracle.